# Setting proxy using firefox webextension with browserSettings.proxyConfig

Tags: javascript, firefox, http-proxy, firefox-addon-webextensions

I've created a Firefox web extension through which I'm trying to change the proxy settings using web extension API. The issue here is `proxyConfig` is expecting the value of `http` or any other type to be of the form `http://proxy_address:port` and is saving the proxy details with `http://` which is a problem as the browser is storing this `http://` in place of `proxy_address` or `ip`. I want to store the proxy without this `http://` prefix. Also, if I remove the `http://` in `http` settings the browser is not storing the proxy as expected.

```
var proxySettings = {
    proxyType: "manual",
    http: "proxy_address:proxy_port"
};
browser.browserSettings.proxyConfig.set({value: proxySettings});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, this is a bug in firefox WebExtensions API, this has been fixed in latest Firefox 60.0 build. The API call/namespace to change the proxy has also changed which needs to be updated in the docs.

```
var proxySettings = {
    proxyType: "manual",
    http: "http://proxy_address:proxy_port"
};

browser.proxy.settings.set({value:proxySettings});
```

Please find the bug report [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460516).